# QString containing printer command in hex

Tags: qt, qstring

I am working on some printer driver and I am importing printer commands from command specification manual and for instance, printer command **Print and Feed Paper** has hexadecimal value of `0x0a`:

```
#ifndef UECOMMANDSET_H
#define UECOMMANDSET_H

#include <QString>

namespace UeCommandSet
{
    namespace TSM210
    {
        static const QString CMD_LF="\x0A";
    }   // namespace
}   // namespace

#endif // UECOMMANDSET_H
```

Is this command representation corrent, i.e., will `QString` hold `0x0a` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I tested it as follow:

```
static const QString CMD_LF= "\x0A";

qDebug() << CMD_LF.size();
qDebug() << (int)CMD_LF.at(0).toLatin1();
```

So, the first line gives 1, and second one gives 10 which is correct. Also you can use the following code to set CMD_LF to 0x0A

```
static const QString CMD_LF= "\n";
```

Comment: If you need more complex multi symbols commands have a look at QByteArray::fromHex method

Comment: @mehmetta but how do I append **decimal number** at the end of, for instance, `CMD_LF` string - some printer commands request parameters?

Comment: You can use QString::append() method. For example
`
    QString str;
    unsigned char c = 'c';
    str.append(65);
    str.append(c);
    qDebug() << str;
`
This gives "Ac"